# (Beautiful Soup) How to extract data from HTML tags

Tags: python, sqlite, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2

So far I have started with this. I can't get the normal text from div.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
get = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("https://example/com/").read()).findAll('div', {'class':'h4 entry-title'})
import sys
for  i in get:
print i
```

How can I scrap data from this HTML please ? I only need these color name and paragraph.

```
<div class="h4 entry-title">
<a href="https://example/com/01/">RED</a>
</div>
<p>
I am paragraph red
<p>

<div class="h4 entry-title">
<a href="https://example.com/02/">WHITE</a>
</div>
<p>
I am paragraph white
</p>


<div class="h4 entry-title">
<a href="https://example.com/03/">PINK</a>
</div>
<p>
I am paragraph pink
</p>
```

*My Questions:*

1. How can I scrap data from this HTML? I need the text and paragraph only.

**Output I need in console:**

```
RED I am paragraph red
WHITE I am paragraph white
PINK I am paragraph pink
```

2. How can I import these set of data into a SQL file automatically?

**Output Database table(name,description) I want:**

```
name: RED,WHITE,PINK
description: I am paragraph RED, I am paragraph WHITE, I am paragraph PINK
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering question one, write it like this:

```
for div in BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("https://example/com/").read()).findAll('div', {'class':'h4 entry-title'}):
    for a in div.findAll('a'):
        print a.text
    for p in div.findAll('p'):
        print p.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

(...)
connection = ...
cursor = connection.cursor()
(...)

bs = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("https://example/com/").read())

names = []
descriptions = []
for title in bs.findAll('div', {'class': 'h4 entry-title'}):
    name = title.find('a').text
    description = title.find('p').text
    sdesc = description.split()
    sdesc[-1] = sdesc[-1].upper()
    names.append(name)
    descriptions.append(' '.join(sdesc))
    print name, description

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (name, description) VALUES (%s, %s)", (','.join(names), ', '.join(descriptions))
connection.commit()
```

Comment: thanks man ! but I am using mysql. Is it possible to dump into my database automatically from this python code ? I never used cursor into mysql. seems like interesting. looking for your guidance man !