# Python web scraping access value between <a> </a>

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am new to web scraping, apologies if this question has been asked before.

Let's say I have this html code: `<a aria-current="page" aria-label="Current page" href="https://name_webpage.com/">1</a>`

How can I access the value between `<a> </a>`, i.e. 1, with python?

Many thanks!

Comment: You could probably get away with using a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) but for more complex uses you will need a dedicated library such as [beautifulsoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Beautiful Soup) How to extract data from HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181084/beautiful-soup-how-to-extract-data-from-html-tags)

Comment: Best to avoid regex to parse HTML. Use a HTML parser, as in the linked duplicates. There are several related duplicates, do search around for others as well, though some of the answers given there should suffice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers! @costaparas answer solved my problem!

Comment: You should include information about the package you're using to perform the scraping to begin with - a simple web client such as aiohttp or requests? A purpose built tool such as Scrapy? Or a browser driver such as Selenium? There are too many potential answers to the question as it stands.

Answer (score -1):

You're refering to python so I guess youd like to try Beautiful Soup to scrape the html.

With BS4, the content of tags is accessible by addressing the array .contents[] of the tag. The <a> tag should only have one field, so you could probably omit the brackets. Use strip() to get the plain text from the link.

Example code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

doc = '<a aria-current="page" aria-label="Current page" href="https://name_webpage.com/">1</a>'

soup  = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'html.parser')

print(soup.a.contents[0].strip())
```

Result:

```
$ python scrapetest.py
1
$
```